# Flex container alignment for four items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have four items in a flex container which unfortunately have a few problems.

The text doesn't sit next to each other, the cart text isnt centred even though it should be and when I use a google translate to french the div overlaps buttons next to it instead of the buttons moving.

[image]
[image]

Is there any way of moving the individual DIVS when in a flex container?

```css
.flex-container {
  margin: 0;
  /* spacing to screen*/
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="icon 
    icon-login" viewBox="0 0 28.33 37.68"><path d="M14.17 14.9a7.45 7.45 0 1 0- 
    7.5-7.45 7.46 7.46 0 0 0 7.5 7.45zm0-10.91a3.45 3.45 0 1 1-3.5 3.46A3.46 
    3.46 0 0 1 14.17 4zM14.17 16.47A14.18 14.18 0 0 0 0 30.68c0 1.41.66 4 5.11 
    5.66a27.17 27.17 0 0 0 9.06 1.34c6.54 0 14.17-1.84 14.17-7a14.18 14.18 0 0 
    0-14.17-14.21zm0 17.21c-6.3 0-10.17-1.77-10.17-3a10.17 10.17 0 1 1 20.33 
    0c.01 1.23-3.86 3-10.16 3z"/></svg>
  <div id="Icontext">Login</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="icon 
    icon-cart" viewBox="0 0 37 40"><path d="M36.5 34.8L33.3 8h-5.9C26.7 3.9 23 
    .8 18.5.8S10.3 3.9 9.6 8H3.7L.5 34.8c-.2 1.5.4 2.4.9 3 .5.5 1.4 1.2 3.1 
    1.2h28c1.3 0 2.4-.4 3.1-1.3.7-.7 1-1.8.9-2.9zm-18-30c2.2 0 4.1 1.4 4.7 3.2h- 
    9.5c.7-1.9 2.6-3.2 4.8-3.2zM4.5 35l2.8-23h2.2v3c0 1.1.9 2 2 2s2-.9 2-2v- 
    3h10v3c0 1.1.9 2 2 2s2-.9 2-2v-3h2.2l2.8 23h-28z"/></svg>
  <div id="Carttext">Cart</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the simplified generated code for that section and the css. Why does your `.flex-container` have display inline block?

Comment: Sorry the display inline block was a mistake. I've removed it now. What do you mean by simplified generated code?

Comment: To center all 4 elements, you need another flex container which should contains all 4. Check https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ to see how to work with flex.

Comment: @FrancisDuggan As in there might be some stuff in the code that is not needed to reproduce the issue, those code can be removed so it is easier to read. Right now, you only have css for the flex container and 2 of the 4 items in html. We need to see the problem to be able to solve it